# What do you call a bunch of envelopes?

Tags: nouns

An envelope is an object that contains a letter and a recipient. When you have a lots of received envelopes stored in a box or similar,

What word can I use to describe the place where you store them?  I want to use **the plural of that word**.

The same way you describe a bunch of birds as a "flock" of birds; and when you say "flocks of birds", you can describe multiple groups of birds. That's the equivalent word that I need for "envelope", if it even exists.

Comment: Your suggestion, pack,  is as good as any.

Comment: What do you put the envelopes in? Can't you use the plural of that?

Comment: @JJJ I was actually looking at the word for the thing I put them in. Not sure if Postbag is the correct word (not a native speaker and we don't really use the mail in my country). Or maybe it's called a Mailbag?

Comment: @Stan I thought about keeping Pack as my last resort, in case I find something more descriptive

Comment: It really depends on what you put it in, if you put it in a bag then you'd call it a mailbag. If you use something that is not a bag, you wouldn't call it a mailbag. Do you have a picture of what you want to describe?

Comment: @jjj What do you call the place you put the envelopes you have received over time. Like if you're archiving them in a box or something. Similar to storing love letters in a box

Comment: I think you need to add the example sentence that your word would fit into. I would call a lot of envelopes with addresses on such as a mailman would have as a *sack of mail*, plural is then *sacks of mail*. If you want them stored after they have been received (like love letters) then that's very different.

Comment: I'd call it a "wad of envelopes".

Comment: (And don't ask new questions in comments.)

Comment: I see, so they are different things. I'll update my question. I meant to ask one thing.

Comment: If they are bound together with a ribbon, string or rubber band they become a _bundle_ of envelopes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"A stack of envelopes" would sound natural.

Comment: How about a bunch of envelopes?

Answer (score 0):

A stack of envelopes would be the common usage, most likely connected to the usage of stack for several letters.

A stack of enveloper, a stack of letters.

To support this; several letter manufacturers call a collection of envelopes a stack - one of them being Bowers (To which I have no affiliation).

Pack would be used if you were referring to a specific amount; a pack of 5 envelopes, vs a stack of letters (of unspecified quantity).